# Creating lists within lists by sorting

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, gathering

I've been working with lists and am stuck on creating lists within a list based on the first element within that list.
So for instance, if I have the list:

```
> list={{John,42},{Mary,52},{John,30},{Mary,25},{Joe,10}}
```

I would like to return this:

> {{{Joe,10}},{{John,42},{John,30}},{{Mary,52},{Mary,25}}}

As you can see, this is basically a reorganized list within a list based on SortBy[...,First]

I can create the sorted version by simply doing:

```
SortBy[list,First]
```

Which would return:

> {{Joe,10},{John,42},{John,30},{Mary,52},{Mary,25}}

But I would also like for each list to be grouped into another list based on the name

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
GatherBy[SortBy[list, First], First]
GatherBy[Sort@list, First]
SplitBy[Sort@list, First]
Values @ GroupBy[First] @ Sort@list
```

> {{{Joe, 10}}, {{John, 30}, {John, 42}}, {{Mary, 25}, {Mary, 52}}}

```
SortBy[GatherBy[list, First], First]
GatherBy[SortBy[list, {First}], First]
Sort[GatherBy[list, First]] (* thanks: J.M *)
Values @ Sort @ GroupBy[First] @ list
```

> {{{Joe, 10}}, {{John, 42}, {John, 30}}, {{Mary, 52}, {Mary, 25}}}

Comment: `Sort[GatherBy[{{"John", 42}, {"Mary", 52}, {"John", 30}, {"Mary", 25}, {"Joe", 10}}, First]]` works, too.

Comment: @J.M, yes of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like obtained from

```
KeySort[Map[SortBy[#, Last] &, GroupBy[list, First]]]

(* <|Joe -> {{Joe, 10}}, John -> {{John, 30}, {John, 42}}, Mary -> {{Mary, 25}, {Mary, 52}}|> *)
```

or by

```
Values[KeySort[Map[SortBy[#, Last] &, GroupBy[list, First]]]]

(* {{{Joe, 10}}, {{John, 30}, {John, 42}}, {{Mary, 25}, {Mary, 52}}} *)
```

?